# how to get a response in realtime in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Hi I am trying to make a request and receive just the response in realtime using socketIO
and currently I am able to connect to the router but not getting any response as the error shows

**Error: io is not defined.**

If anyone can please help me to resolve this issue.

Below is the necessary code.

ChatPageProvider.dart

```
Future<void> addProduct(String message) async {
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      "Content-Type": "charset=utf-8",
      "Content-type": "application/json"
    };

    const url = 'http://localhost:8080/message/check';

    try {
      var response = await http.post(url,
          headers: headers,
          body: json.encode({
            "text": message,
          }));
      socketIO.init();
      //Subscribe to an event to listen to
      socketIO.subscribe('message', (jsonData) {
        //Convert the JSON data received into a Map
        Map<String, dynamic> data = json.decode(jsonData);
        messages.add(data['message']);
        notifyListeners();
      });
      socketIO.connect();
      //   final getMessage = Message(
      //   text: json.decode(response.body)['message'],
      // );

      print(response.statusCode);
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const notificationdetails = require('../nodePractice/router/notification');
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: "50mb"}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit:"50mb",extended:true}));

io.on("connection",(userSocket) => {
    console.log('Conntected to port')
    io.emit('connected', 80);

})

var server = http.listen(port, ()=> {
    console.log('listening on port' + port)
})

app.use(notificationdetails);
```

notification.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = new express.Router()



router.post('/message/check',async(req,res) => {
    console.log("Success"); // I am able to get till here but then the error occurs
    io.emit("message", req.body)

    try {
        res.status(201).send();
        io.emit("message", req.body)
    }catch(e) {
        res.status(401);
        io.emit("message", req.body)
        res.send(e);
    }
})

module.exports = router
```

error

```
(node:78214) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: io is not defined
```

Comment: There is no `io` defined in your `notification.js` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a file like below, give it a name **socket-io.js**.

```
var io = require('socket.io')(9999);
module.exports = io;
```

Then import it first in your index.js like below snippet.

```
let io = require('./app/utilities/socket-io');

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
...
});
```

Last, you can import the same file in your **notification.js** file as well & try below code.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = new express.Router()
let io = require('./app/utilities/socket-io');


router.post('/message/check',async(req,res) => {
    console.log("Success"); // I am able to get till here but then the error occurs
    io.emit("message", req.body)

    try {
        res.status(201).send();
        io.emit("message", req.body)
    }catch(e) {
        res.status(401);
        io.emit("message", req.body)
        res.send(e);
    }
})

module.exports = router
```